# %Change between static and dynamic values in a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, wordpress

**What am I trying to do?**
I'm trying to make something similar to this:
https://tokenstats.io/

A static manually number (ICO PRICE) that I input myself. This number needs to be % compared to a dynamic number (CURRENT PRICE), pulled from coinmarketcap API: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

**What did I try?**
I'm using wordpress to achieve this. I tried both wpdatatables and tablepress plugins for wordpress https://tablepress.org/. They both support formulas and can calculate the % change between two number values. I can pull the data with this example:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      tr td {text-align: right;}
      table {padding: 5px;}
      table.striped tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
      thead {border-bottom: 2px solid black; font-weight: bold;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h1>Price Ticker</h1><h5>Updates every minute</h5></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td width="120">Currency</td>
                <td width="170">Entry price</td>
                <td width="170">Current price</td>
                <td width="170">%change</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>                
              <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey;">
                <td>Bitcoin</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td class="blink" id="btc"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>             
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <script>
            $.ajaxSetup({async: false}); // must set to synchronous to be able to set the global variables sbd, steem, etc...
            function getPrices() {
              url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=USD';
              $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                btc = parseFloat(data[0].price_usd).toFixed(2);
                btcchange = parseFloat(data[0].percent_change_24h).toFixed(2);
              });

              $("#btc").html("$" + btc.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,') + " " + (btcchange > 0 ? '<i style="color:green;">\u2191' + Math.abs(btcchange) + '%</i>' : '<i style="color:red;">\u2193' + Math.abs(btcchange) + '%</i>'));

            }
            getPrices(); // get prices
            setInterval(function () {
              getPrices();
              $(".blink").fadeOut("slow").fadeIn(); // fade effect for fun
            }, 60000); // then get prices every 60 seconds
          </script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**What is the problem?**
The problem I encountered using tablepress was that I can't simply paste all that code into a cell and then calculate the % change, it does not support that. I can show the current price easily by putting the code in a shortcode and displaying that in a cell, but I can't make calculations on that, because shortcodes output is a string, and the formula works with numbers.

**How can I do this?**
So my question is, how can I make something similar to the website I linked, in a simple matter? I'm no coder, that's why I'm trying to achieve this using wordpress and a table plugin. I just want to find a way to add my own tokens in an easy way. Does anyone know of a good solution to this?

Thank you.